# React. Functional vs class components

Tags: reactjs, stack, mern

Is it possible to use both Functional and Class Components in a single React App?. I am building a website UI with React, back end has been build with NodeJS. The templates I am using was build with Class Components where they new Components I am introducing are Functional with Context API's. Can they work together or is it necessary I convert all the Class Components to Functions?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both in the same app. They are 100% compatible.

- Each one can pass props to the other
- They will be both compiled into plain javascript.

Quote from [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) :

> In React apps, whether a component is stateful or stateless is
> considered an implementation detail of the component that may change
> over time. You can use stateless components inside stateful
> components, and vice versa.

Another quote from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) :

> "Crucially, Hooks work side-by-side with existing code so you can
> adopt them gradually. There is no rush to migrate to Hooks. We
> recommend avoiding any “big rewrites”, especially for existing,
> complex class components. It takes a bit of a mindshift to start
> “thinking in Hooks”. In our experience, it’s best to practice using
> Hooks in new and non-critical components first, and ensure that
> everybody on your team feels comfortable with them."

Comment: I would add: "but it's strongly discouraged work with both implementations" :)

Comment: Thank you very much but why the discouragement then?

Comment: It's just my opinion but I think is a matter of readability. Hooks logic is soo different from components logic that after a while you are not undesting what is happening on your app. Component uses a flow based on onComponentDidMount, functional component uses useEffect and so on. But I repeat, it's just my personal opinion.

Comment: Okay noted. Thank you very much

Comment: Sometimes you don't have the choice. If you arrive in a codebase in stateful and you want to write in stateless, you can. Here is a quote from reactjs.org :
"Crucially, Hooks work side-by-side with existing code so you can adopt them gradually. There is no rush to migrate to Hooks. We recommend avoiding any “big rewrites”, especially for existing, complex class components. It takes a bit of a mindshift to start “thinking in Hooks”. In our experience, it’s best to practice using Hooks in new and non-critical components first, and ensure that everybody on your team feels comfortable with them."

Comment: Thank you very much @YoannBuzenet for your input. It has given me more clarity